# Convert boto3 output to convenient format

Tags: python, datetime, boto3

I am getting the below output using describe_snapshots function in boto3

> u'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 7, 4, 21, 42, tzinfo=tzutc())

I wish to convert it into proper date so that I can proceed with sorting the snapshots and removing the ones which are older than a particular number of days.

Is there a python functionality which can be used to attain this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly already the format you need. datetime objects are easily comparable / sortable. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

import boto3


ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
account_id = 'MY_ACCOUNT_ID'
response = ec2.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=[account_id])
snapshots = response['Snapshots']

# January 1st, 2017
target_date = datetime(2017, 01, 01)

# Get the snapshots older than the target date
old_snapshots = [s for s in snapshots if s['StartTime'] < target_date]

# Sort the old snapshots
old_snapshots = sorted(old_snapshots, key=lambda s: s['StartTime'])
```

docs: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

Really late to this post but I recently ran into this. I am assuming you're comparing the dates by hand/eye vs comparing the datetime objects programatically. Or you're debugging and you just want to see the date/time in the json objects in human readable format.

I found that the converter in the [aws aha samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-health-aware/blob/main/handler.py#L596-L598) works really well.

```
def myconverter(json_object):
    if isinstance(json_object, datetime.datetime):
        return json_object.__str__()
```

From there you can just pass your original event/message from boto to json.dump and get the converted json string back

```
In [34]: print(json_msg)
{'arn': 'arn:aws:service:region::X', 'service': 'SERVICE', 'eventTypeCode': 'SOME_CODE', 'eventTypeCategory': 'CAT', 'eventScopeCode': 'SCOPE', 'region': 'us-east-1', 'startTime': datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'endTime': datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'lastUpdatedTime': datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM, SS, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'statusCode': 'CODE' }

In [35]: json_msg = json.dumps(json_event, default=myconverter)

In [36]: print(json_event)
{'arn': 'arn:aws:service:region::X', 'service': 'SERVICE', 'eventTypeCode': 'SOME_CODE', 'eventTypeCategory': 'CAT', 'eventScopeCode': 'SCOPE', 'region': 'us-east-1', 'startTime': "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS-OH:OS", 'endTime': "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS-OH:OS", 'lastUpdatedTime': "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS-OH:OS" , 'statusCode': 'CODE' }
```

Answer (score -2):

probably needs more code from your end - but it almost seems like you're the one making it output that way (or something you're using is by default)

aws returns this format:

`<startTime>YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ</startTime>`

so im guessing you are somewhere using datetime.datetime() instead of something else on the date fields? (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Boto3 returns datetime objects. All AWS SDKs convert values that represent a time to a Date object native to the language in which they're written.

Comment: I found that using aws cli was more easier than boto3 in terms of the usability

Comment: well yeah but you wont always have a console (serverless/lambda/etc)

Comment: yes in lambda you will have to use boto3....but cli is definitely more straightforward